# Is there an approved method to completely remove an app?

Tags: django, django-models

I have an app which was misconceived, and I would now like to delete it completely. I cannot find anything in the Django documentation about the right "blessed" way to do this.

I tried commenting out its models and running `makemigrations` but this threw errors because its views.py could not import them. If I removed its views from `urls.py` and tried, then `makemigrations` did not recognise that anything had changed.

Is it as simple as removing it from `installed_apps` in `settings.py`, removing its code, and manually deleting its  one small model table from the DB? Or will the fact that it had an `admin.py` mean that there are dangling references left somewhere?

I'm using Django 2.2 if it makes any differerence

Comment: Isn't it as simple as just deleting the app folder and removing references in your settings.py and urls.py?

Comment: @sur.la.route It can get more complicated if _other_ apps had foreign keys to this apps models. Then one would would have to remove the foreign keys making sure not to miss any, one cannot even remove the app from `INSTALLED_APPS` unless one goes and edits the migration files manually to remove those dependencies.

Comment: @sur.la.route that's what I'm asking. A long time ago, before Django had native migrations (was using South), removing an app bit me, but I cannot remember any details from then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From experience:

1. Remove any foreign key relations to this delete_app's models
2. Make the migrations for those removals and apply
3. Delete all the references to delete_app from other apps
4. Delete all the code in delete_app except migrations
5. Make the migrations for the deleted models and apply

After this I'm still left with delete_app's migrations and its entry in `INSTALLED_APPS` because other migrations from other apps still refer some dependency on delete_app's migrations. Haven't had time to check how I can remove it completely, or if there is a recommended way of doing this, but hope this helps.